# PHP date() in offline WAMP differs from system time

Tags: php, date

why does the PHP date() in my offline WAMP different from my system time? how can i sync it?

Answer (score 6):

You should set the default timezone. You can do this in `php.ini`, just add the following line:

```
date.timezone ="Europe/Stockholm"
```

You should obviously change Europe/Stockholm to your timezone. If you don't have access to php.ini, you can use [date_default_timezone_set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and pass your timezone as a parameter, like:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Stockholm");
```

Here is a list of [supported](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) timezones.